# Bulk rename files in powershell and add a count to each filename

Tags: powershell, count, rename, bulk

I am able to bulk rename files in a directory OR substitute each file name with a count, however I need both combined.

Bulk rename (keep first 2 charachters of original name):

```
Get-ChildItem * |  
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + $_.Extension }
```

(partially hard coded solution, I know!)

Alternatively, add count:

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem * | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0}.xlsx’ -f $count++) }
```

(I am not even dreaming about trailing 0s)

I tried to combine both things, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

My failed attempt:

```
$count = 1 
Get-ChildItem * |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] -f $count++ + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) works. You need a format string with a placeholder (`{0}`) in order to make that operator work. I would also recommend putting grouping parentheses around that expression, even though that shouldn't be required in this case. Just to be on the safe side.

```
('foo {0} bar' -f $some_var) + $other_var
```

With that said, you apparently want to append the value of the counter variable to the fragment from the original file name rather than using that fragment as a format string. For that you can simply concatenate the counter to the fragment, just like you do with the extension.

For the counter to work correctly you also need to specify the correct scope. The way you're using it defines a new variable `$counter` in the local scope of the scriptblock every time a file is renamed, so the variable `$counter` in the parent scope is never incremented. Use the `script:` or `global:` scope modifier to get the variable you actually intend to use.

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem * |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + $script:count++ + $_.Extension }
```

If you do want to use the format operator instead of string concatenation (`+`) you'd use it like this:

```
$count = 1
Get-ChildItem * |
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}{2}' -f $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0], $script:count++, $_.Extension }
```

Comment: Ansgar, renaming works, but I noticed that it also adds a count to the subfolders of the current directory. How can I specify that I want only specific file extensions to be counted, or alternatively only files inside a given directory (so no subfolders).

Comment: @monechka You can use a `Where-Object` filter for restricting the `Get-ChildItem` results. `Get-ChildItem` also has some parameters that allow discrimination what the cmdlet should return.

Answer (score -1):

To have the $count counted up, you have to go with the loop.

```
$count = 1 
Get-ChildItem * | foreach-object { Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] -f 
 count++ + $_.Extension } }
```

% is the alias for the foreach-object cmdlet you used in the "add count" approach.
Just added it to you failed attempt.

Comment: I now get this error:

 At line:2 char:87
+ ... -object { Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] -f count++ ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-f' operator.

Comment: At line:2 char:88
+ ... { Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] -f count++ + $_.Ex ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'count++' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: sorry, had to split, comment was too long

Comment: Not only is your claim factually incorrect (you can absolutely increment a counter in a scriptblock used with `Rename-Item`), but the code in your answer is even more broken than it was in the question.